# SQL Statement to find if row exists

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to use a select statement to see if a value exists in a table. If it doesn't exist it should return a message. My problem is though that my select statement is returning a count of 0 when the value clearly exists in the table. I thought it might just be a problem with my code.

```
function check_trainer_location() {
global $wpdb;
$islocation = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wppl_friends_locator WHERE member_id='" . bp_displayed_user_id() . "'");
if(is_user_logged_in() && bp_is_my_profile() && count($islocation) < 1) {
return 'No location set';
}
}
```

Any idea why this would be returning a count of 0 and not 1 as it should (i echoed the count before to see what it returned).

Comment: I even tried replacing the bp_displayed_user_id() with the actual ID value to trip it up, still returned 0

Comment: $islocation = Select count(columnName) From tableName where id='something' ?

Comment: Sorry. On my phone so I couldn't write the full thing but I think it should work unless you have others restrictions

Comment: Nope no luck there :(

Comment: Are you able to run a similar query on your table? Test it outside the function.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table; should return the number of rows in the table. And adding WHERE id=127; will return the count of rows with that id. Assuming its unique, it should be either 1 or 0

Comment: What data type is 'member_id'? A string or a int/long?

Comment: i ran a query in phpmyadmin and it returned 1 like it should. The data type for member_id is bigint(30)

Comment: Anyone able to help with this?

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the initial problem of the count not changing to 1, the problem was {$wpdb->prefix}wppl_friends_locator. Since the table was called wppl_friends_locator it was assuming that the table had a WP_ prefix attached to it, which it did not.

Unfortunately this raised another problem. When deleting the location to get the count to revert to 0, it just doesnt change and assumes the count is still 1 and wont go back now.